# How can I keep users data updated swift/mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, swift, database

I am creating a mobile app and am using MySQL and php for the backend. My question is how can I keep users data up to date, even after the user is logged in. For example, lets say `User1` logs in to my app and he has 0 followers. After `User1` has logged in, `User2` "follows" `User1`. So the data in the MySQL table will show that `User1` has 1 follower, but the data on `User1`'s screen will still show that he has 0 followers because the query for the users followers has already been called. How can I keep the data updated on the client side?

Comment: periodic ajax request

Comment: This topic should be closed as his question covers different platforms with no actual lines of code.

Comment: What site should this be asked on then? I didn't think a stack overflow post was required to contain code....

Comment: Apart from periodic ajax calls I propose to use socketio or websockets,